# Обнаружение лица, глаз и улыбки в реальном времени в Python

Tags: pyqt5, opencv, интерфейс, python-3.6

Пишу программу по обнаружению лица, глаз и улыбки в режиме реального времени в Python. Интерфейс реализовываю в PyQt5. Эта моя первая программа с интерфейсом и возник вопрос подключения кнопки по обнаружению(Detection) к основному коду.

Ниже приведен код, программа запускается, кнопки Start и Stop Webcam работают, но при нажатии на Detection программа перестает функционировать:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Ту же прогу писала в консоли, там все работает,не хватает опыта по оформлению.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Буду очень благодарна.

```
import sys
import cv2

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from pygments.formatters import img


class interface(QDialog):
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    eyeCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
    smileCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_smile.xml')

    def __init__(self):
        super(interface,self).__init__()
        loadUi('interface.ui',self)
        self.image=None
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start_webcam)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stop_webcam)
        self.detectionButton.clicked.connect(self.detection)

    def start_webcam(self):
        self.capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)

        self.timer=QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
        self.timer.start(5)


    def update_frame(self):
        ret,self.image=self.capture.read()
        self.image=cv2.flip(self.image,1)
        self.displayImage(self.image,1)

    def detection(self):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
        faces = self.classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,
                                                 scaleFactor=1.3,
                                                 minNeighbors=4,
                                                 flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,
                                                 minSize=self._min_size)


        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            if self.chkFace.isChecked():
                cv2.rectangle(self.image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = self.image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

            if self.chkEyes.isChecked():
              eyes = self.eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
              for(ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
                  cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

            if self.chkSmile.isChecked():
              smile = self.smileCascade.detectMultiScale(
            roi_gray,
            scaleFactor= 1.5,
            minNeighbors=15,
            minSize=(25, 25),
              )
              for (xx, yy, ww, hh) in smile:
                  cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (xx, yy), (xx + ww, yy + hh), (0, 
         255, 0), 2)

    def stop_webcam(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def displayImage(self,img,window=1):
        qformat=QImage.Format_Indexed8
        if len(img.shape)==3: #[0]=rows, [1]=cols, [2]=channels
            if img.shape[2]==4:
             qformat=QImage.Format_RGBA8888
        else:
                qformat=QImage.Format_RGB888

        outImage=QImage(img,img.shape[1],img.shape[0],img.strides[0],qformat)
        #BGR>>RGB
        outImage=outImage.rgbSwapped()

        if window==1:
            self.imgLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(outImage))
            self.imgLabel.setScaledContents(True)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = interface()
        window.setWindowTitle('Detection Project')
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Уверен, что проблема в `self.classifier.detectMultiScale`. У вас нигде не объявлено поле `classifier`. Добавьте в код хук для отлова исключений, чтобы при последующей ошибке получить понятную ошибку с трассой стека: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/hook_exceptions_in_Qt.py

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо за подсказку, попробую применить